# bootstrap 4 - card and tab panel side by side

Tags: bootstrap-4

Yes masters, i want make user profile page with bootstrap with card and tab panel side by side but unsuccess, it's my code, help please..

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="card">
  <h5 class="card-header text-center"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> '.$_SESSION['user']->username.'</h5>
      <img src="http://www.bkpsdm-boltim.info/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/no_photo.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

  <div class="card-body">
    <a target="_self" href="http://www.facebook.com" class="fab fa-facebook"></a> <a target="_self" href="http://www.facebook.com" class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></a> <a target="_self" href="http://www.twitter.com" class="fab fa-twitter"></a> <a target="_self" href="http://www.whatsapp.com" class="fab fa-whatsapp text-success"></a>
    <label class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</label>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
      <h6><small class="text-muted">Register Date:'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_SESSION['user']->registerdate).'</small></h6>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10">
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </div>

</nav> 
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suppose English is not your first language, but you'll need to try to be a bit more clear on what you need to do. I kinda get that you want to have a Bootstrap card and panel side by side; but not exactly sure of the issue itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
  <div class="col-5 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
    <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-header text-center"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> '.$_SESSION['user']->username.'</h5>
      <img src="http://www.bkpsdm-boltim.info/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/no_photo.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

      <div class="card-body">
        <a target="_self" href="http://www.facebook.com" class="fab fa-facebook"></a>
        <a target="_self" href="http://www.facebook.com" class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></a>
        <a target="_self" href="http://www.twitter.com" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
        <a target="_self" href="http://www.whatsapp.com" class="fab fa-whatsapp text-success"></a>
        <label class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</label>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <h6><small class="text-muted">Register Date:'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_SESSION['user']->registerdate).'</small></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-7 col-md-5 col-lg-10">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
      </div>

    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad, look at it again

Comment: Yes it's working perfectly but how to leave a some blank to top ?

Comment: You would have to add some margin if you need it; try adding the class `mt-5` to the `<div class="container-fluid">`; I'll add it to the answer